# How to remvove header from first page while rendering as word(doc) file

Tags: quote

I am working on quote which is generating as a word document . Now I am facing an issue like I don't want header in first page .

I trying to use @Page : First CSS  which is not working for me .
Any help is highly appreciated ,please help .

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
@page:first{

    @top-right {

      content: ""
          font-weight: lighter;
          font-size:8pt;
        }
    }
```